# Linking f90 including NetCDF code

Tags: compiler-errors, linker, macports, fortran90, netcdf

I'm trying to build a f90 program that uses NetCDF libraries. The compilation of the objects goes well. But at the linking stage, which links with NetCDF libraries, there's a problem:

```
gfortran-mp-4.7 -g -O2 -Wall -o myProg myObj1.o myObj2.o /opt/local/lib/libnetcdff.a /opt/local/lib/libnetcdf.a

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_H5Aclose", referenced from:
      _nc4_rec_read_vars in libnetcdf.a(libnetcdf4_la-nc4file.o)
      _nc4_rec_read_vars_cb in libnetcdf.a(libnetcdf4_la-nc4file.o)
      _nc4_rec_write_metadata in libnetcdf.a(libnetcdf4_la-nc4hdf.o)
      _write_attlist in libnetcdf.a(libnetcdf4_la-nc4hdf.o)
      _nc4_rec_write_types in libnetcdf.a(libnetcdf4_la-nc4hdf.o)
      _write_netcdf4_dimid in libnetcdf.a(libnetcdf4_la-nc4hdf.o)
 .
 . [Similar paragraphs]
 .
  "_curl_easy_strerror", referenced from:
      _ocfetchurl_file in libnetcdf.a(liboc_la-ochttp.o)
      _ocfetchurl in libnetcdf.a(liboc_la-ochttp.o)
      _ocfetchlastmodified in libnetcdf.a(liboc_la-ochttp.o)
      _ocping in libnetcdf.a(liboc_la-ochttp.o)
  "_curl_version_info", referenced from:
      _oc_curl_protocols in libnetcdf.a(liboc_la-occurlfunctions.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not a very experienced programmer, but what I get from this is that apparently it cannot find stuff like `_H5Aclose`. Google tells me this belongs to a `hdf5` library. But I seem to have this:

```
pwd:/opt/local/include >> ls | grep hdf
hdf5.h
hdf5_hl.h
```

I've also tried adding these paths explicitly to the linker (although this was not specified in the makefile)

```
gfortran-mp-4.7 -g -O2 -Wall -o myProg myObj1.o myObj2.o -L/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib /opt/local/lib/libnetcdff.a /opt/local/lib/libnetcdf.a

gfortran-mp-4.7 -g -O2 -Wall -o myProg myObj1.o myObj2.o -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/lib /opt/local/lib/libnetcdff.a /opt/local/lib/libnetcdf.a
```

But I get the same error message. I'm on Mac OS 10.8, and have installed both gcc (which came with gfortran) and netcdf-fortran from macports. Anybody know's what's wrong, or how I should proceed to figure it out?

Comment: Do you have `hdf5.mod` somewhere on your HDD?

Comment: No, it's not under /usr, /opt, or /Applications/Xcode, so I don't think I have it

Comment: I would think that having the `hdf5.mod` file would be necessary, but I don't use NetCDF so I'm not the most qualified person to answer.

Comment: I tried re-installing hdf5 (again from macports) but that didn't give me the mod file. Maybe I'll need to build from source?
But I'm not convinced it's the hdf5 that's missing, because I don't think the other undefined symbols such as "_curl_easy_strerror" are part of hdf5. I think rather I must be doing the linking wrong

Comment: I'd build from source so that you can enter `./configure --enable-fortran` (plus whatever other options you want) so that the relevant `.mod` files are made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetCDF4 and HDF5 both come with helper applications

- nf-config
- nc-config
- h5fc
- h5cc

Did they get installed? I would use them by default, for your case:

```
gfortran-mp-4.7 -g -O2 -Wall -o myProg myObj1.o myObj2.o `nf-config --fflags --flibs`
```